# Convert JSON date string to NSDate objects using Restkit Entitymapping

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I have a `JSON` which contains the following

```
dateStart: "2013-10-14 8:30:00",
dateStop: "2013-10-14 9:00:00"
```

Now I want to map these datestrings as `NSDates` in my `core database`. I'm using `Restkit` for mapping my `JSON` into my coredatabase. Now is there I way how I can transform these strings to `NSDates` and save it as an NSDate?

I've tried this:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        //dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

        [RKEntityMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
```

But it seems not working. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: What version are you using? You should not specify the time zone. You should specify the locale.